# Remove "" from NSArray

Tags: ios, nsarray

I have some data that I am getting from the web and putting in an array when I log the array it looks like this

```
(
"Chicken Tagine",
"Grilled Pita"
)
```

But I need to remove the "", from the strings as it is causing problems when I try to use the array how can I go about doing this?

When I log an array that I make like this there are no ""

```
NSArray *array = @[@"one", @"two"];
NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

This logs them with no ""

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: What problems are you referring to? Those are strings, the quotation marks are there to indicate that they are strings.

Comment: The quote characters are not in the elements of the array. That's purely an artifact of `NSArray`'s `description` method which is used when logging. The quotes are added for any strings which have spaces, punctuation, or "special" characters that might lead to ambiguity. Your program should never depend on the specifics of the description of an array or how it logs itself.

Comment: @shim can you see edit

Comment: Quotation marks are there for clarity, they are not part of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotes are part of how an array is printed by `NSLog`. They only exist when there are spaces in the string, and cannot be removed:

```
  NSLog(@"%@", @[@"one",
                 @"two",
                 @"Chicken Tagine",
                 @"Grilled Pita"]);
```

Produces:

```
2015-02-02 09:42:46.834 My App[822:25368] (
    one,
    two,
    "Chicken Tagine",
    "Grilled Pita"
)
```